# What's the need of translating the virtual address to physical address?

Tags: arm, memory

These are the points I read in the Memory Management Unit of ARM architecture:

1. Virtual addresses (or logical addresses) are addresses provided by the OS to processes.
2. One virtual address space per process
3. Programs use virtual addresses. As a program runs, the hardware (with help
   from the operating system) converts each virtual address to a physical address.
4. The conversion of a virtual address to a physical address is called address
   translation
5. When the MMU is turned off, the virtual acts as output onto the physical address.

After reading the fifth point, I want to understand why do the address translation is required? Is it because the size of virtual memory is smaller than physical memory? And why/when would the MMU is turned off?

Comment: Imagine two processes having the same virtual address for one of their variables.

Comment: It sounds like you're missing the basics of virtual memory and virtual addressing. Have you read and understood the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory)  on it?

Comment: @PlasmaHH Oh! Why that case arises?

Comment: @TonyM Yes I read before posting (from other websites too) but since u mentioned I will go through it once again (maybe I missed something which you are saying).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Virtual address translation is needed for several reasons:

1. More ram can be addressed than there is available. For instance, the CPU in my laptop can address 256TB of memory, whereas it only has 8Gb of memory. This extra address space lets the kernel allocate far more memory than is available, and it can swap pages to disk for applications that aren't being used.
2. Virtual address translation prevents memory fragmentation. Imagine a program that frequency allocates and deallocates large objects, the size of a memory page. If the addresses were physical, the memory space would quickly become fragmented, with no large areas of memory free. However, the kernel can remap the virtual and physical addresses so that there's always a large section of memory free, and if part of the address space is fragmented, so what? Only the pages of memory that are in use need to be backed by physical memory, and there's plenty of address space to put new allocations.
3. Virtual addresses give better security. Remember those CPU bugs earlier this year, Spectre and Meltdown? They rely on knowing some information about the mapping of virtual addresses for different processes and the kernel. If you turn of virtual addressing, they and other attacks become a lot easier because you then know the addresses of the kernel and other processes.

As to why you would turn off the MMU, I can only guess that it's referring to the state of the MMU during startup of the processor, before the kernel has set up the page table. You wouldn't turn the MMU off during normal operation of an operating system.

Comment: It is an ARM, it is quite often run without OS or with an RT OS that doesn't care about memory separation.

Comment: True, however if the ARM has a MMU, it's not one of the cortex M micro controllers, so it's not unreasonable to put an OS on it. And if you're using one without a multitasking OS, then the MMU really doesn't matter, and is probably not used.

Comment: That's not quite true. On (some?) ARMs the data cache won't work without MMU enabled.